# Solving an Equation in gekko

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, equation, gekko

This is a part of my code:

```
import gekko as GEKKO
for i in range(0,4,1):
    m = GEKKO()
    x = m.Var()
    e_i1 = R_n[0,0] * A_slice[i,0] + R_n[1, 0] * A_slice[i, 1]
    e_i2 = R_n[0, 1] * A_slice[i, 1] + R_n[1, 1] * A_slice[i, 1]
    r = get_determinante(R_n)
    d = P[0,i]
    m.Equation(e_i1*R_n[0,1]*x + e_i1*R_n[1,1]*A_slice[i,4] - e_i2*R_n[0,0]*x + e_i2*R_n[1,0]*A_slice[i,4] == r * d)
    m.solve()
    print(x)
```

however it is not printing x.

Any Reasons?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not pringing x"? Is there an error or seomthing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing the value of `x` as:

```py
print(x.value)
```

The variable `x` is a Gekko variable type and the results are loaded into `x.value` as a numpy array. To access the value, you can print `x.value` or `x.value[0]` to get just the first element of the array.

You are creating a new Gekko model, variables, and equations on each loop. You can also declare an `x` array of values with `x=m.Array(m.Var,4)` and solve all of the equations and variables simultaneously without a loop. This may help speed up your code. If you do this then you'll need to print each value of `x` as:

```py
print([x[i].value[0] for i in range(4)])
```

Here is a self-contained example with array functions:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
# variable array dimension
n = 3 # rows
p = 2 # columns
# create array
x = m.Array(m.Var,(n,p))
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(p):
      x[i,j].value = 2.0
      x[i,j].lower = -10.0
      x[i,j].upper = 10.0
# create parameter
y = m.Param(value = 1.0)
# sum columns
z = [None]*p
for j in range(p):
   z[j] = m.Intermediate(sum([x[i,j] for i in range(n)]))
# objective
m.Obj(sum([z[j]**2 + y for j in range(p)]))
# minimize objective
m.solve()
print(x)
```